# Multi-color text animation but only on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

The color is changing but when I remove the mouse it still keeps changing the colors

```js
var color_text  = document.getElementById('nav');
var color_text1 = document.getElementById('nav1');
var color_text2 = document.getElementById('nav2');
var color_text3 = document.getElementById('nav3');

var color = new Array(4);
color[0] = "blue";
color[1] = "green";
color[2] = "yellow";
color[3] = "red";

function displaycolor() {
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)
  color_text.style.color = color[x];
  setTimeout(displaycolor, 1000);
}

function displaycolor1() {
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)
  color_text1.style.color = color[x];
  setTimeout(displaycolor1, 1000);
}

function displaycolor2() {
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)
  color _text2.style.color = color[x];
  setTimeout(displaycolor2, 1000);
}

function displaycolor3() {
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)
  color_text3.style.color = color[x];
  setTimeout(displaycolor3, 1000);
}

function rmvdis() {
  clearTimeout(); //when mouse leaves
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a id="nav"  onmouseover="displaycolor();"  onmouseout="rmvdis();" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav1" onmouseover="displaycolor1();" onmouseout="" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav2" onmouseover="displaycolor2();" onmouseout="" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav3" onmouseover="displaycolor3();" onmouseout="" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

So, I  want something like when the mouse moves out the color becomes normal and only changes the color when the mouse is on top.

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/m6fb3ask/

Comment: `clearTimeout();` makes no sense. You need to specify _which_ interval you want to clear. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactored your code:

HTML

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a id="nav"  onmouseover="displaycolor(0);"  onmouseout="rmvdis(0);" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav1" onmouseover="displaycolor(1);" onmouseout="rmvdis(1);" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav2" onmouseover="displaycolor(2);" onmouseout="rmvdis(2);" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav3" onmouseover="displaycolor(3);" onmouseout="rmvdis(3);" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var color_text  = document.getElementById('nav');
var color_text1 = document.getElementById('nav1');
var color_text2 = document.getElementById('nav2');
var color_text3 = document.getElementById('nav3');

var color = new Array(4);
color[0] = "blue";
color[1] = "green";
color[2] = "yellow";
color[3] = "red";

var color_texts = [color_text, color_text1, color_text2, color_text3];

var intervalID;

function randomize() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
}

function displaycolor(index) {
  if (intervalID) return;
  color_texts[index].style.color = color[randomize()];
  intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    color_texts[index].style.color = color[randomize()]
  }, 1000);
}

function rmvdis() {
  clearInterval(intervalID); //when mouse leaves
  intervalID = undefined;
}
```

Explanation: You will need `setInterval` and you will need to store the id of the interval and pass that. You can work with timeouts as well, but it's unintuitive to use that for this purpose. I have got rid of the duplicated functions and used parametrization instead.

Comment: yes m still learning I did realize the mistake that I didn't give an id to clear the interval

Comment: @RaviSingh that's normal and understandable. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using CSS3 animation.

```css
.text {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.text:hover {
  animation: animateColors 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes animateColors {
  0% { color: red; }
  50% { color: green; }
  100% { color: blue; }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Dummy Text</div>
```

Comment: But this doesn't use a randomized sequence.

Answer (score 1):

**There are multiple solutions with varying degrees of randomness:**

**Solution 1 (not random & css-only):**

Might I suggest using CSS instead of JavaScript for performance and simplicity:

```css
.nav>li>a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  animation: color-shift 1s alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes color-shift {
  0% {
    color: blue;
  }
  33% {
    color: green;
  }
  66% {
    color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a id="nav" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav1" href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav2" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav3" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Obviously `animation-direction: alternate` doesn't provide the randomness of `Math.random()` but it looks about the same.

---

**Solution 2 (more random & some JavaScript):**

If the first solution doesn't float your boat you can use JavaScript to get a truly random sequence of colors each time you hover (but keep it the same throughout one hover-event):

```js
function newColors() {
  let colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "red"];
  let color_names = ["--color1", "--color2", "--color3", "--color4"];

  colors.forEach(function(color) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * color_names.length);
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(color_names.splice(random, 1)[0], color);
  });
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color1: blue;
  --color2: green;
  --color3: yellow;
  --color4: red;
}

.nav>li>a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  animation: color-shift 1s alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes color-shift {
  0% {
    color: var(--color1);
  }
  33% {
    color: var(--color2);
  }
  66% {
    color: var(--color3);
  }
  100% {
    color: var(--color4);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a id="nav" onmouseover="newColors()" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav1" onmouseover="newColors()" href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav2" onmouseover="newColors()" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav3" onmouseover="newColors()" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

**Solution 3 (truly random & JavaScript):**

You could also just use JavaScript to get a random sequence of colors (closest to your solution) but you will find that it looks worse, as true randomness seems very repetitive in small input sets like this one.

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "red"];
let interval;

document.querySelectorAll(".nav > li > a").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", rainbow, false);
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", stop, false);
});

function rainbow() {
  this.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  interval = setTimeout(() => rainbow.call(this), 250);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  this.style.color = "black";
}
```

```css
.nav>li>a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a id="nav" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav1" href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav2" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav3" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

**Solution 4 (truly random but no repetition & JavaScript):**

Same as solution 3 but without the repeating colors:

```js
const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "red"];
let last = -1;
let interval;

document.querySelectorAll(".nav > li > a").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", rainbow, false);
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", stop, false);
});

function rainbow() {
  let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  this.style.color = colors[i !== last ? i : i + 1];
  interval = setTimeout(() => rainbow.call(this), 250);
  last = i;
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  this.style.color = "black";
}
```

```css
.nav>li>a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a id="nav" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav1" href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav2" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a id="nav3" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just opened this and was happy to get answers but I also solved it and I learned from your answers too thanks here's how I did it

```js
var repeater;
var repeater1;
var repeater2;
var repeater3;

var color_text = document.getElementById('nav');
var color_text1 = document.getElementById('nav1');
var color_text2 = document.getElementById('nav2');
var color_text3 = document.getElementById('nav3');

var color = new Array(4);

color[0] = "blue";
color[1] = "green";
color[2] = "yellow";
color[3] = "red";

function displaycolor() {
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)
  color_text.style.color = color[x];
}

function displaycolor1() {
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)
  color_text1.style.color = color[x];
}

function displaycolor2() {
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)
  color_text2.style.color = color[x];
}

function displaycolor3() {
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)
  color_text3.style.color = color[x];
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a id="nav" onmouseover="repeater=setInterval(displaycolor,100);" onmouseout="color_text.style.color='gray';clearInterval(repeater);" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav1" onmouseover="repeater1=setInterval(displaycolor1,100);" onmouseout="color_text1.style.color='gray';clearInterval(repeater1);" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav2" onmouseover="repeater2=setInterval(displaycolor2,100);" onmouseout="color_text2.style.color='gray';clearInterval(repeater2);" href="port/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav3" onmouseover="repeater3=setInterval(displaycolor3,100);" onmouseout="color_text3.style.color='gray';clearInterval(repeater3);" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```